# Crear un visor de noticias y guardarlo a pdf como binario en la base de datos

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Junto con saludar, me gustaría recibir de sus consejos para crear un visor de noticias en el cual uno puede escribir, colocándole estilo a las letras (negrita, cursiva). Después, todo ese texto, poder generar un archivo pdf en el cual pueda guardarlo como binario en la base de datos.
La idea es que pueda procesar el texto, respetando su estilo de letras y crear el pdf con Itexsharp o reportviewer. Si tienen algún ejemplo, o idea, se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: son dos preguntas las que planteas, la edicion de contenido con formato y la otra la generacion del pdf, pero no entiendo par aque necesitas guardar el pdf en la db, si podrias guardar el texto con formato directamente y regenerar el pdf en base a esta cuando lo necesites

Comment: la edicion la puedes reslizar con cualquier componente de editor de html, entonces luego usar una libreria que permita convertir el html a pdf, creo que Itexsharp tiene uno pero es una extension

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, es lo necesito para reenviarlo mas tarde por correo el pdf.

Comment: ok pero lo generas y lo envias, no lo guardas en la db. Lo que persistes si es el texto con formato, pero puedes usar cualquier componente de edicion que aplique notacion html, despues conviertes este a pdf